# how to explain resource directory dimension qualifier in android studio

Tags: android

I find someone uses dimension qualifier to support multiple screens。for example,
values-hdpi-480x800，values-hdpi-640x960。It's very useful，but I don't found doc about dimension qualifier。I only find swdp，wdp。I want to know android whether have a doc about dimension qualifier and how to explain dimension qualifier. I found a qualifier dimension in android studio new resource directory window。
This is new resource directory window:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

swdp = smallest width dp

Eg. Only on screens with a width greater than this will this resource be used.

The android documentation on supporting multiple screens covers this logic. Seehttp://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I know swdp and wdp.How to explain values-hdpi-480x800,Android support Dimension Qualifier like 480x800.